# Angular img src not shown local file path while in html it is working

Tags: html, angular

I have the following simple html code

```
<html>
<body>
<img src= "file://C:/Users/amira/Desktop/71zNWbTHzxL._SL1500_.jpg" width="200px">
</body>
</html>
```

and it is working with no problem and shown the image as following

[image]

and then I am using it in angular project hosted on IIS but the image is not shown, please view the following screenshot

[image]

**EDIT**

I noticed that the url is redirect to the following : http://localhost:4200/file:/C:/Users/smacrsadmin/Desktop/71zNWbTHzxL.*SL1500*.jpg

I do not know why it append localhost to the url

Comment: Put the image in the `src/assets` and use a relative path.

Comment: The fact it is not showing has nothing to do with Angular, the browser simply won’t allow this.

Comment: @MikeOne but it allow it in html

Comment: please @MikeOne check my edit

Comment: I don’t know what more to tell you: “ Non-local web pages cannot access local files in Chrome or any modern web browser.”. This is a security thing. Also, I still do not understand why you need this in the first place. That image would only work if YOU visit the webpage..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use local file such as image in angular then you need to put your image in assets folder and used as

```
<img src="assets/name-of-file">
```

Comment: the system will be deployed on a server that has storage partition, and the angular should read data from the storage, so it is not possible to add them to asset folder